# MongoDB CRUD operations for various types of data in Go

Tags: go, mongodb

First of all I am a newbie in Go. I wrote a CRUD REST API that consists of handlers, a database layer and so on, and it contains a lot of code duplication. I see some patterns here, and I know how to reuse code in some other languages like JS or Java using generics or dynamic types.

What are my options in Go? Note that I don't want to use `interface{}`.

Here is my `userdb` CRUD set of function that create, update and so on.

```
package userdb

import (
    "github.com/atsman/interviewr-go/models"
    "github.com/op/go-logging"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

var log = logging.MustGetLogger("db.user")

func GetUserC(db *mgo.Database) *mgo.Collection {
    return db.C(models.CollectionUsers)
}

func Create(db *mgo.Database, user *models.User) error {
    return GetUserC(db).Insert(user)
}

func Update(db *mgo.Database, id *bson.ObjectId, user *map[string]interface{}) (error, *models.User) {
    var updatedUser = models.User{}
    err := GetUserC(db).UpdateId(id, bson.M{
        "$set": user,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err, &updatedUser
    }

    err = GetUserC(db).FindId(id).One(&updatedUser)
    return err, &updatedUser
}

func List(db *mgo.Database, query *bson.M) (error, *[]models.User) {
    var users []models.User
    err := GetUserC(db).Find(bson.M{}).All(&users)
    return err, &users
}

func Delete(db *mgo.Database, id *bson.ObjectId) (error, *models.User) {
    var user = models.User{}
    err := GetUserC(db).FindId(id).One(&user)
    if err != nil {
        return err, &user
    }

    err = GetUserC(db).RemoveId(id)
    if err != nil {
        return err, &user
    }

    return nil, &user
}
```

And here is my `companydb` package. Its goals are almost the same except with the `Company` model.

```
package companydb

import (
    "github.com/atsman/interviewr-go/models"
    "github.com/op/go-logging"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

var log = logging.MustGetLogger("db.company")

func GetCompanyC(db *mgo.Database) *mgo.Collection {
    return db.C(models.CollectionCompanies)
}

func Create(db *mgo.Database, company *models.Company) error {
    return GetCompanyC(db).Insert(company)
}

func Update(db *mgo.Database, id *bson.ObjectId, user *map[string]interface{}) (error, *models.Company) {
    updatedCompany := models.Company{}
    err := GetCompanyC(db).UpdateId(id, bson.M{
        "$set": updatedCompany,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err, &updatedCompany
    }
    err = GetCompanyC(db).FindId(id).One(&updatedCompany)
    return err, &updatedCompany
}

func List(db *mgo.Database, query *bson.M) (error, *[]models.Company) {
    var companies []models.Company
    err := GetCompanyC(db).Find(bson.M{}).All(&companies)
    return err, &companies
}

func Delete(db *mgo.Database, id *bson.ObjectId) (error, *models.Company) {
    company := models.Company{}
    err := GetCompanyC(db).FindId(id).One(&company)
    if err != nil {
        return err, &company
    }

    err = GetCompanyC(db).RemoveId(id)
    if err != nil {
        return err, &company
    }

    return nil, &company
}
```

The same duplication exists in my handlers. There is a lot of stuff like get struct from JSON, check for errors and so on. I am thinking of some generic stuff.

So, I think the question is quite easy for guys with some experience. How can I generalize this? Or I shouldn't care at all, maybe it is not a big deal here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also starting out in go (although I used GAE's Datastore), and have spent some time thinking about this. I considered 3 options:

## 1 Code Generation

I think code generation would be a solid way to approach this solution. There's even a library starting out called [streetCURD](https://github.com/Isted/StreetCRUD) for PostgreSQL.
Code generation seems like a common way to do things in go. There is also a golang code generation tool called [gen](http://clipperhouse.github.io/gen/).

## 2 Don't Generalize

Depending on how many times you will copy and paste this, it may not be worth for you to generalize it. However, I find that after a few structs I start doubting this route... and others are not generalizing too: [Example1](http://thenewstack.io/make-a-restful-json-api-go/). [example2](https://github.com/benjamin-thomas/golang-crud-example).

## 3 Interfaces

I ended up using interface{} for somethings (like error checking) which you stated you are not interested in. I felt it made the code more readable, which is my goal.

Looking over your code, it seems like you are interested in a method that return a user or a company- depending in the input, interface{} would be the way to go... (pun not intended).

Since I am just starting out, I'd love to see better responses to this question.